# Stata: Reading in data and specifying var type

Tags: import, stata, variable-types

I am importing a dataset into Stata with a lot of variables  (~250), a majority of which need to be read into Stata as strings, so I was wandering if instead of writing a painfully long dictionary file, I could just tell Stata to read all variables as strings, and then go back in and convert the few variables back to numeric as needed.

Answer (score 1):

You could certainly try that. Stata has a `destring` command intended to be as smart as possible, but you may need to do more work than just `destring, replace`.